# Chat Firebase convert in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View fa = getView();

    ll = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container,false);

    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);

    if (!UtilChat.checkConnection(getActivity())){
        UtilChat.initToast(getActivity(), "LOL");

    }else{
        bindViews();
        verificaUsuarioLogado();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();
    }
    return ll;
}
  private void bindViews(){
    contentRoot = fa.findViewById(R.id.contentRoot);
    edMessage = (EmojiconEditText)fa.findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);
    btSendMessage = (ImageView)fa.findViewById(R.id.buttonMessage);
    btSendMessage.setOnClickListener(this);
    btEmoji = (ImageView)fa.findViewById(R.id.buttonEmoji);
    emojIcon = new EmojIconActions(getActivity(),contentRoot,edMessage,btEmoji);
    emojIcon.ShowEmojIcon();
    rvListMessage = (RecyclerView)fa.findViewById(R.id.messageRecyclerView);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                               at sky.alien.korenovskguide.ChatActivity.bindViews(ChatActivity.java:381)
>                                                                               at sky.alien.korenovskguide.ChatActivity.onCreateView(ChatActivity.java:125)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are invoking findViewById on a null object.

you are invoking findViewById on your view fa, which is wrong.

You have to use

```
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container,false);
TextView myText = myView.findViewById(R.id.my_Text_view);
```